# load image from the Top in TabWidget from PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qtabwidget

[image]Below code, image loading from the specific Path and placing on the bottom of the Window.Here i need to load image from the top.So for that i need to change the placement of the Tab Widget(Tab01,Tab02,Tab03).
I am unable to load the image from the top and unable to change the position of the Tab Widget.How to do this and how to load the Image from the top.

```
import re,sys,os
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
class projs(QtGui.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(projs,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle(" V1.0 ")  
        tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget() 
        proj    = QtGui.QWidget() 
        asset   = QtGui.QWidget() 
        shots   = QtGui.QWidget() 
        tab_widget.addTab(proj, "Tab01") 
        tab_widget.addTab(asset, "Tab02")
        tab_widget.addTab(shots, "Tab03")
        self.projPathLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Project Path ",proj)
        self.projPathLabel.setGeometry(10,20,100,25)
        self.assetPathLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Project ",asset)
        self.assetPathLabel.setGeometry(20,20,100,25)
        self.shotPathLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Project ",shots)
        self.shotPathLabel.setGeometry(20,20,100,25)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(tab_widget)         
        self.setLayout(vbox)      
        p1_vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(proj)
        proj.setLayout(p1_vbox)
        p2_vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(asset)
        asset.setLayout(p2_vbox)
        p3_vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(shots)
        shots.setLayout(p3_vbox)
        vuvupic = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\Users\name\Documents\config\Logo2.jpg")
        label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        label.setPixmap(vuvupic)
        vbox.addWidget(label)
app = QtGui.QApplication([]) 
win = projs() 
win.resize(410,390)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "from the top," do you mean that you want to have the image placed above the the TabWidget? QLayouts are ordered in the same order of vbox.addWidget() calls, which means you could just reorder the function calls to put the picture on top.

```
import re,sys,os
from PyQt4 import QtGui,QtCore
class projs(QtGui.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(projs,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle(" V1.0 ")  
        tab_widget = QtGui.QTabWidget() 
        proj    = QtGui.QWidget() 
        asset   = QtGui.QWidget() 
        shots   = QtGui.QWidget() 
        tab_widget.addTab(proj, "Tab01") 
        tab_widget.addTab(asset, "Tab02")
        tab_widget.addTab(shots, "Tab03")
        self.projPathLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Project Path ",proj)
        self.projPathLabel.setGeometry(10,20,100,25)
        self.assetPathLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Project ",asset)
        self.assetPathLabel.setGeometry(20,20,100,25)
        self.shotPathLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Project ",shots)
        self.shotPathLabel.setGeometry(20,20,100,25)
        vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        vuvupic = QtGui.QPixmap("C:\Users\name\Documents\config\Logo2.jpg")
        label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        label.setPixmap(vuvupic)
        vbox.addWidget(label)
        vbox.addWidget(tab_widget)         
        self.setLayout(vbox)      
        p1_vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(proj)
        proj.setLayout(p1_vbox)
        p2_vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(asset)
        asset.setLayout(p2_vbox)
        p3_vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(shots)
        shots.setLayout(p3_vbox)
app = QtGui.QApplication([]) 
win = projs() 
win.resize(410,390)
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Also, for moderately sized project, you may want to look into using QtDesigner to build layouts. Googling "pyqt designer" will give you plenty of blogs and tutorials for getting started.

Comment: Thanks Dval.Perfectly Working